# Boost Http Server Example Crashes at boost::thread on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, segmentation-fault, boost-asio

I'm trying to compile and run the following example on Ubuntu 10.10

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/server3/

but it crashes at:

```
// Create a pool of threads to run all of the io_services.

std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> > threads;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < thread_pool_size_; ++i)
{
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> thread(new boost::thread(
          boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service_)));
    threads.push_back(thread);
}
```

Call Stack:

```
Thread [1] 573 [core: 0] (Suspended : Signal : SIGSEGV:Segmentation fault)  
    boost::thread::start_thread() at 0x8064a64  
    boost::thread::thread<boost::_bi::bind_t<unsigned int, boost::_mfi::mf0<unsigned int, boost::asio::io_service>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<boost::asio::io_service*> > > >() at thread.hpp:204 0x805e8c6   
    http::server3::server::run() at server.cpp:57 0x8059cbf 
    main() at HttpServer3.cpp:38 0x8048522
```

However, it does NOT crash on Ubuntu 11.04, for the same Eclipse CDT project.

Any advice?

Comment: My initial guess is that Boost.Thread isn't built properly on your 10.10 installation.

Comment: I built the boost lib successfully on 10.10.  The funny thing is on 11.04, I did get some errors building boost, but it works fine.

Comment: You might be right. See my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems ildjarn's initial guess might be correct.

I found there are two versions of the boost lib on my Ubuntu 10.10.  I removed them thoroughly, and installed the latest one, and the issue was gone.